# how to add Android Path in mac

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using Ionic2 and I want to run android in mac: when I used Command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

I had this error:

```
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Android SDK not found. Make 
sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set 
the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

although I have SDK installed in that location:

```
/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
```

and when I write this command in terminal:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
```

and then write:

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

I had these pathes only:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

what should I do to add path correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I added the directory **/etc/paths.d**

```
sudo mkdir /etc/paths.d
```

and created a file **android-sdk**

```
sudo vi /etc/paths.d/android-sdk
```

Add your paths in the file and save