# `flutter doctor` report error `Android toolchain - develop for Android devices`

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-2.3

I run `flutter doctor` in my Mac:
there comes an issue below:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale
    zh-Hans-CN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
      ANDROID_HOME to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.
```

But I have installed Android SDK in my Mac this path `/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx`.

before ask this question I have follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779889/how-to-add-android-path-in-mac) to add the `/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx` in my `/etc/paths.d/android-sdk` file,   and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53772200/7693832) add `path-to-android-sdk/tools` and `path-to-android-sdk/platform-tools`.

but there is still have this issue.

---

**EDIT-01**

This is the `echo $PATH`:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/delo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/Users/delo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin:/Users/delo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.6/bin:/Users/delo/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
```

Comment: can you post the result of calling `echo $PATH` here

Comment: updated it. please check .

Comment: change last attribute `/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx/platform-toolsdelo` to `/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools`

Comment: Its a multi-copy, it is `/Users/delo/software/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools`.

Comment: try setting ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 1):

I see your $PATH have add the ANDROID SDK PATH and its `tools` and `platform-tools` PATH, but did not config the flutter PATH, but you can still run `flutter doctor` command, there should be copy error.

in your case, there must be `ANDROID_HOME` variable config error,

you should follow the correct way :

append the

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/flutter/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME="/path/to/your/android-sdk"
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

to

then you just `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the PATH of Android SDK Command-Line Tools and Android SDK Build Tools.

Put the lines at the end of the .bachrc file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/XXX/Android/Sdk/"
export PATH="$PATH:${ANDROID_HOME}cmdline-tools/latest/bin/:${ANDROID_HOME}build-tools/33.0.0/:${ANDROID_HOME}platform-tools/"
```

Note that **latest** and **33.0.0** must be changed according to your installation.